# Is there any public available documentation about Honeywell FHDB files?

Tags: datasets

I am new to aviation, my task is to read FHDB (Honeywell Fault History Data Base) files.
They seem to be kind of tab separated values but with special bytes at line start.
like: `0D 0A A7 09`
Some lines in some files begin with `#` after the mentioned bytes.
On the other hand i know the meaning of certain columns like flight leg or flight phase.
I am more interested in the technical aspects on reading and decoding such files (are there other files that use same format?)

I would appreciate any public info or tools (i only found this https://apps.apple.com/vn/app/honeywell-forge-mxadvisor/id1002600365) that help with this task. For reading i will use Python.

Comment: `0d 0a` is a Windows-style line break. `09` is a tab.